# Flip toggle switch (jQuery) on change not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fire an event (which sends POST data to an external script) when the state of a toggle switch changes, but I cannot even get the most basic example to work...

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<label for="flipswitch">Option:</label>
<select name="flipswitch" id="flipswitch" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>`
```

JavaScript (in the `<head>` section):

```
<script>

    $('#flipswitch').change(function(){
        console.log("flipswitch");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z5ABx/1/ - did you add the script in a dom ready handler - any error in your browser console

Comment: Looks fine, are you sure you have jQuery imported and there's no other JS errors? [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EU26J/)

Comment: There is no problem with the script itself but with the position of the script tag. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. Are you sure you're looking at the console output? Do you have the code in the $('document').ready(function() {

)};

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! This was the issue, I had it below the switch before and the code still was not working....but it is all good now!

Comment: I'd appreciate the credit - I need it. Mark as answered somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that at the execution time of script, there is no element with the specified id. There are several ways how to overcome this problem.

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $('#flipswitch').change(function(){
            console.log("flipswitch");
        });          
    });
</script>
```

or you may simply move the script tag from head tag to the bottom of body tag and it will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#flipswitch").on("change", function(e){
    console.log("flipswitch");
});
```

Could be because the .change is deprecated in favor of .on()

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/naUmA/13/